# Url rewrite issue in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

We need URL rewrite in laravel. my URL is:
http://aditlinux.com/blog/video/monsoon-with-romance

Now we remove "blog" keyword in this URL but got routing issue.
Actual we want URL like http://aditlinux.com/video/monsoon-with-romance

Comment: I mean we need SEO friendly url.

Comment: Can you please provide what you've tried, and please give more information about which laravel version you use and how did you define your routes.

Answer (score 0):

See if it helps you. I removed the /public from the url with the following code. Create .htaccess file in your root with the following code.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ blog/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should modify your routes.php file, find there the rule which related to that page, and remove there "blog" part